# PowerShell: how to count number of rows in csv file?

Tags: command-line, powershell, csv, count, powershell-1.0

How can I count the number of rows in a csv file using powershell? I tried something like

```
Get-Content -length "C:\Directory\file.csv"
```

or

```
(Get-Content).length "C:\Directory\file.csv"
```

but these result an error.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pipe it to the `Measure-Object` cmdlet

```
Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but it is terribly slow compared e.g. to GNU Unix utils wc.exe.

Comment: That is because wc.exe would be the equivalent of (Get-Content).Length which while it is much faster than Import-CSV, it is also a potentially incorrect solution as pointed out by stej since it would not account for rows with multiline fields.

Comment: (took ~1 minute for a 100 MB file)

Answer (score 64):

Get-Content and Measure-Object are fine for small files, but both are super inefficient with memory. I had real problems with large files.

When counting rows in a 1GB file using either method, Powershell gobbled up all available memory on the server (8GB), then started paging to disk. I left it over an hour, but it was still paging to disk so I killed it.

The best method I found for large files is to use IO.StreamReader to load the file from disk and count each row using a variable. This keeps memory usage down to a very reasonable 25MB and is much, much quicker, taking around 30 seconds to count rows in a 1GB file or a couple of minutes for a 6GB file. It never eats up unreasonable amounts of RAM, no matter how large your file is:

```
[int]$LinesInFile = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'c:\filename.csv'
 while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $LinesInFile++ }
```

The above snippet can be inserted wherever you would use get-content or measure-object, simply refer to the $LinesInFile variable to get the row count of the file.

Comment: Faster than any other solutions shown here. Less than 5 seconds to sort out a 500mb csv file.

Comment: You also should dispose reader ($reader.Dispose()) after use or you risk holding file opened until you close your PS session.

Comment: If using powershell add "write-output $LinesInFile" at end of block above to get the value on screen.

Comment: just add `$LinesInFile` at the end and you will see the number.

Comment: Great if i need to get  count for lists of file in a folder.. how do i do that?

Comment: best solution! 10 gb file!

Comment: Note that it's better practice to specify `while ($null -ne $reader.ReadLine()) { ... }` due to how comparison operators can sometimes work like filters. https://rencore.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/

Comment: @Linga Search for powershell scripts that process lists of files in a loop, insert my snippet inside the loop and specify the file name as a variable inside your loop.

Answer (score 10):

Generally (csv or not)

```
@(Get-Content c:\file.csv).Length
```

<del>If the file has only one line, then, it will fail.</del> (You need the @ prefix...otherwise if the file has one line, it will only count the number of *characters* in that line.

```
Get-Content c:\file.csv | Measure-Object -line
```

But both will fail if any record takes more than one row. Then better import csv and measure:

```
Import-Csv c:\file.csv | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count
```

Comment: Last one seems to generate an error: Select-Object : Cannot expand property "count" because it has nothing to expand.
At line:1 char:64
+ Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv | Measure-Object | Select-Object  <<<< -expand count

Comment: Weird, `Measure-Object` should return an object that has a property Count. Try to remove the `|Select-Object ...` and you will see what it returns.

Comment: You're probably using PowerShell v1. In v1, 'Select-Object -expand propertyName' throws an error when the result is a scalar (one object). Upgrade to v2 and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I'm using version 1.0, it's one of the tags of this question.

Comment: I check only PowerShell tag. And silently assumed that nobody uses v1.0. Sorry :)

Comment: Ok, no problem, thank you for your contribution. Btw, I'm using still Win XP, AFAICS, PowerShell 2.0 is not available for Win XP?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use unix like comand in powershell.

If you file test.csv
Then command to get rowcount is

```
gc test.csv | Measure-Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv).count
```

or

```
$a=Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv
$a.count
```

Comment: I get an `OutOfMemoryException` using this approach on a large file. Using `Get-Content | Measure-Object` works with a limited amount of memory..

Answer (score 0):

`(Import-Csv C:\Directory\file.csv).count` is the only accurate one out of these.

I tried all of the other suggestions on a csv with 4781 rows, and all but this one returned 4803.