# How to count the number of rows?

Tags: powershell

This command will give some properties of an `ls` item:

```
PS> (ls)[0]|select *

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\F...
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\F...
PSChildName       : myscript
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\F...
PSIsContainer     : True
Mode              : d-----
BaseName          : myscript
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Name              : myscript
FullName          : C:\ps\myscript
...
```

I want to count how many line the output have.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855814/powershell-how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-csv-file) gives a solution based on `Measure-Object` to count a CSV, but it is not applied here. Is there any method to do this? As I count one by one,the last result should be `23`.

Comment: You could do `(((ls)[0]|select *|Out-String) -split '\r?\n' |?{$_}).Count`, or you could do `@((ls)[0].psobject.properties).Count` - but *why*?

Comment: What are you really after? Are you looking for `DirectoryInfo`'s properties?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I cannot find your `psobject` from `(ls)[0]|Get-Member`

Comment: @yode: that's because `Get-Member` will not list `psobject`. But it does exist on every object. And if you already know about `Get-Member`, why haven't you used `(Get-Member -MemberType Properties).Count`?

Comment: @vonPryz I just want to count how many line the output of  `(ls)[0]|select *`

Comment: @yode `(ls)[0] | Get-Member -Force`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks..

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen What's meaning of your `?` in your `'\r?\n'`?And I think that comment deserve a answer for reading..

Comment: @yode `\r?` means the carriage return character (`\r`) is optional.

Comment: @yode Again, *why* would you want to count the number of output lines?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Well,I really have no specific aim.I just curious about how to do. :)